# The element I need to use is on the page, but Robot Framework cannot find it

Tags: robotframework

I am working on a webpage that has 1 visible textbox.

```
<div class="col-xs-5 pull-right search-bar">
            <input class="form-control search-box ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="searchBox" placeholder="Enter a supplier or a catalog name" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()">
        </div>
```

When I try to wait for the element to be visible using:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=//input[@id="searchBox"]    60
```

I get an error saying:

```
Element 'xpath = //input[@id="searchBox"]' did not appear in 1 minute.
```

I have searched for element using the xpath above, which gives me only 1 result when I search by hand in the browser.  I have tried using the div tag to search for it as well.  The element is on the page immediately and does not take time to load.

Comment: Can you rule out that the input box with given xpath isn't inside iframe ? Cuz, if it is, you need to select that frame first.

Answer (score 0):

**You could try this format:**

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element  xpath://input[@id='searchBox']  60
```

*The explicit locator strategy is specified with a prefix using either syntax strategy:value or strategy=value. The former syntax is preferred, because the latter is identical to Robot Framework's named argument syntax and that can cause problems. Spaces around the separator are ignored, so id:foo, id: foo and id : foo are all equivalent.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using id, you don't need to use xpath, so

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element  id=searchBox    60
```

Shoud be fine.

Also, to access the element, you need to make sure that:
1) It's visible
2) It's enabled
3) There is not another element above it (like overlay elements)

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  It turns out that the problem is that there is a separate iframe that this searchbox is in.